# Enum properties make my WinForms designer crash

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-forms-designer

After switching our .Net cf solution from Visual studio 2005 to 2008, the designer view for all controls which use enum properties have broken down. With the error message:

The type 'Microsoft.CompactFramework.Design.UnsafeUserControl' has no property named 'PropertyName'.

If I change the property to an int it works, but then I loose all my nice Enum-descriptions in  the designer.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

And yes, we set DesktopCompatible true inDesignTimeAttributes.xmta. It worked in VS 2005.

Comment: No idea why - seems perfectly valid to me.